# copy id="uniqueid" as name="uniqueid" with find/replace & regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a HTML form which currently has unique id's for each input (or select) like so.

example 1

```
<input type="number" id="qty-a-row" min="0" max="999" autocomplete="off" value="" style="border:0px; outline:0px; display:inline-block; width:50px;" />
```

example 2

```
<select id="ps_a_row" autocomplete="off" style="width:324px; border:0px; outline:0px; display:inline-block">
```

each id is unique. I'm now trying to add in a name=""  with the same value as every id="" found so example 1 above becomes.

```
<input type="number" id="qty-a-row" name="qty-a-row" min="0" max="999" autocomplete="off" value="" style="border:0px; outline:0px; display:inline-block; width:50px;" />
```

and example 2 becomes...

```
<select id="ps_a_row" name="ps_a_row" autocomplete="off" style="width:324px; border:0px; outline:0px; display:inline-block">
```

and so on for every id="anything" it finds.

I'm using notepad++ and with regex ticked currently trying...

```
Find = id="(.*)"
Replace = id="\1" name="\1"
```

but this is only finding some id's and duplicates all other tags it finds after the id it finds too.

The complete code for the form I'm trying to edit is here...
https://pastebin.com/ZAE4Gffk

Comment: What about tags that already have `name` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find id="([^"]+)" and replace it with `id="\1" name="\1"` , but you shouldnt use regex for HTML manipulation. Use appropriate tools for that.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5CLaXg/1)